# update control thread safe

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

How do you go about modifying text values or number values to a textbox control or a numbericUpDown control or adding items and/or sub items to a listview control or updating a progress bar from within a thread, without having to create multiple definitions such as a new function AND a new delegate?

Answer (score 1):

I created a thread safe set of extended functions for a set of controls i needed for an app i created that required a lot of threaded updates to a form. The class adds the methods directly in to the controls, so making accessing the controls thread safe requires very minimal code alteration. Simply add this class into your project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
  public static class TSFormExtenders
  {
    #region Control
    public static void SetEnabledTS(this Control x, bool s)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          x.SetEnabledTS(s);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        x.Enabled = s;
      }
    }

    public static bool GetEnabledTS(this Control x, bool def = false)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        bool m_ret = def;
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          m_ret = x.GetEnabledTS();
        }));
        return m_ret;
      }
      else
      {
        return x.Enabled;
      }
    }

    public static void SetTextTS(this Control x, String s)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          x.SetTextTS(s);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        x.Text = s;
      }
    }

    public static String GetTextTS(this Control x, String def = "")
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        String m_ret = def;
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          m_ret = x.GetTextTS();
        }));
        return m_ret;
      }
      else
      {
        return x.Text;
      }
    }

    public static void SetVisibleTS(this Control x, bool s)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          x.SetVisibleTS(s);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        x.Visible = s;
      }
    }

    public static bool GetVisibleTS(this Control x, bool def = true)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        bool m_ret = def;
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          m_ret = x.GetVisibleTS();
        }));
        return m_ret;
      }
      else
      {
        return x.Visible;
      }
    }

    public static void SetSizeTS(this Control x, Size s)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          x.SetSizeTS(s);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        x.Size = s;
      }
    }

    public static Size GetSizeTS(this Control x)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        Size m_ret = new Size();
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          m_ret = x.GetSizeTS();
        }));
        return m_ret;
      }
      else
      {
        return x.Size;
      }
    }
    #endregion

    #region CheckBox
    public static void SetCheckedTS(this CheckBox x, bool s)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          x.SetCheckedTS(s);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        x.Checked = s;
      }
    }

    public static bool GetCheckedTS(this CheckBox x)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        bool m_ret = false;
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          m_ret = x.GetCheckedTS();
        }));
        return m_ret;
      }
      else
      {
        return x.Checked;
      }
    }
    #endregion

    #region NumericUpDown
    public static void SetValueTS(this NumericUpDown x, Decimal s)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          x.SetValueTS(s);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        x.Value = s;
      }
    }

    public static Decimal GetValueTS(this NumericUpDown x)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        Decimal m_ret = 0;
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          m_ret = x.GetValueTS();
        }));
        return m_ret;
      }
      else
      {
        return x.Value;
      }
    }

    public static void SetMinTS(this NumericUpDown x, Decimal s)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          x.SetMinTS(s);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        x.Minimum = s;
      }
    }

    public static void SetMaxTS(this NumericUpDown x, Decimal s)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          x.SetMaxTS(s);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        x.Maximum = s;
      }
    }
    #endregion

    #region ProgressBar
    public static void SetValueTS(this ProgressBar x, Int32 s)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          x.SetValueTS(s);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        x.Value = s;
      }
    }

    public static Int32 GetValueTS(this ProgressBar x)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        Int32 m_ret = 0;
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          m_ret = x.GetValueTS();
        }));
        return m_ret;
      }
      else
      {
        return x.Value;
      }
    }

    public static void SetMinTS(this ProgressBar x, Int32 s)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          x.SetMinTS(s);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        x.Minimum = s;
      }
    }

    public static void SetMaxTS(this ProgressBar x, Int32 s)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          x.SetMaxTS(s);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        x.Maximum = s;
      }
    }
    #endregion

    #region ListView
    public static void AddItemTS(this ListView x, ListViewItem s)
    {
      if (x.InvokeRequired)
      {
        x.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          x.AddItemTS(s);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        x.Items.Add(s);
      }
    }

    public static void AddItemTS(this ListViewItem x, System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem s)
    {
      if (x.ListView.InvokeRequired)
      {
        x.ListView.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs a)
        {
          x.AddItemTS(s);
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        x.SubItems.Add(s);
      }
    }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

Comment: I use [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) (behind a small wrapper) which abstracts everything out and is easy to call so the synchronization is left at the call-site without extra boilerplate. Most of the time, I find that operations should be done together - so leaving it at the call site is cleaner, more efficient, and allows choosing sync or async behavior as required.